# VLOOKUP with criterion of max

Tags: excel, excel-formula

lets say I have a `Table1` as follow:

```
ID    |  Value  
________________  
 1    |    0    
 2    |    0    
 1    |    1    
 3    |    1    
 1    |    0    
 2    |    0   
 1    |    0    
 2    |    0  
 3    |    0    
 4    |    1  
 1    |    0    
 5    |    0
```

and I have a second table that contains unique `IDs` from `Table1`.
In `Table1` `ID` may repeat, but each `ID` can have at most one `1` in `Value` column, the rest is `0`.
How can I write `VLOOKUP` like formula that will tell me if given `ID` has `1` in any occurence?

I would like to get smth like

```
ID    |  Value  
________________  
 1    |    1    
 2    |    0    
 3    |    1    
 4    |    1    
 5    |    0
```

with SQL I would write smth as  `SELECT ID, max(Value) from Table1 group by ID`, or even instead of `max` would use `sum`.
Also to mention: `Table1` will be in separate file from my output table and the `Value` will be just one of many columns, therefore I cannot use Pivot Tables

Comment: Some good answers already, but will leave `CountIf()` in the comments, which can tell if how many "somethings" exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to go about it, and I'm assuming that your values are more complicated than your example, so here is one way:

=MAX(IF(A$2:A$13=E3,B$2:B$13))

Where A2:A13 is your IDs, B2:B13 is the value, and E3 is the start of your reference table.  **This is an array formula and needs to be confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER**

[image]

If it's as simple as 1 or 0, you should use the answer that @dominique gave.

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution is easier than you might think:

```
=SUMIFS(B$2:B$13,A$2:A$13,1)
```

*What are you doing? You are summing everything? I just want to know where the 1 is, no need to sum it?*
Well: you seem to have two possible values: either all 0's, either all 0's and just one 1: if you search for that 1, or if you take the sum, the result is the same :-)

*Ok, that's a neat trick, but what if I decide there might be more than one 1?*
Well: just translate a number, larger than 1, to 1, which you can do with this formula:

```
=IF(E2,1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try on the following formula-

```
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(A2:A13),MAXIFS(B2:B13,A2:A13,UNIQUE(A2:A13)))
```

This will work like `SQL`. It will also work if you have more values than one.

[image]